# How to perform load testing for windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Want to know how many visitors can visit the site running on the server before before the server dies?

What to know how fast the hard drive is performing.

Comment: Is this IIS based? Which hard drive are you referring to? In the Web Server or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some useful tools here:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/231282/en